# How do I implement relational/nested observables?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a `Row` class, which will be shown on a page, and child `Rows` will be shown, nested beneath their parent `Row`. There is no maximum depth to nested rows.

```
export class Row {
    constructor(
        public name: string,
        public id: number,
        public parentId: number,
    ) {}
}
```

all `Rows` are stored and managed within the `RecipeService`, which `RowComponent` holds a subscription to.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Field } from 'src/app/classes/field';
import { Row } from 'src/app/classes/row';
import { RecipeService } from 'src/app/services/recipe.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipe-row',
  template: `
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row" height="30px" *ngFor="let row of rows.filter(r => r.parentId = thisRow.parentId); let i = index">
      <app-recipe-row [thisRow]="row"></app-recipe-row> 
    </div>  
  </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./recipe-row.component.css']
})
export class RecipeRowComponent implements OnInit {

  rows: Row[];
  fields: Field[][];

  @Input() thisRow: Row;

  constructor(public rs: RecipeService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadRows();
    this.loadFields();
  }

  loadRows(): void {
    this.rs.rowO$
      .subscribe(
        rows => this.rows = rows
      );
  }

  loadFields(): void {
    this.rs.fieldO$
      .subscribe(
        fields => this.fields = fields
      );
  }
}
```

This issue that I'm having (other than probably mis-using rxjs), is that bindings cannot contain assignments, so I'm not sure how to best cascade these child-rows

Comment: Can you create a demo stackblitz. I'm not clear what your problem is at the moment

Comment: Hi Kurt, The issue is in the RowComponent .html template. specifically `<div class="row" height="30px" *ngFor="let row of rows.filter(r => r.parentId = thisRow.parentId); let i = index">`. Im attempting to recursively create RowComponents whenever the current row has child rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem you're having is that you have a complex expression in `*ngFor`.

I would move the filter into your model and keep your HTML as simple as possible.

html

```html
<div class="col">
  <div class="row" height="30px" *ngFor="let row of rows">
    <app-recipe-row [thisRow]="row"></app-recipe-row> 
  </div>  
</div>
```

You will also need to sort out your filter. You're currently matching parentId to parentId, when you need to match parentId to id.

component.ts

```js
rows: Row[];

loadRows(): void {
  this.rs.rowO$.subscribe(rows => {
    if (!this.thisRow) {
      this.rows = rows.filter(row => !row.parentId);  
    } else {
      this.rows = rows.filter(row => 
        row.parentId && row.parentId === this.thisRow.id);
    }
  });
}
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z8j8te

This demo isn't using observables just to keep things as simple as possible. Unless the observable you're subscribing to is doing something weird, I doubt that will be causing you problems.

Comment: my observable was doing some weird stuff that broke your example, but you did show me everything I needed to get my code working. Thanks!